# Transpose Fields csv, Python (Numpy or Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I need to do somthing like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lpCC.png)

```
ID  20170101    20170106    20170111
A   0.31        0.1           0.2
B   0.3         0.2           0.1
C   0.11        0.12          0.13
D   0.3         0.3           0.4

ID  DATES   NDVI_mean
A   20170101    0.31
A   20170106    0.1
A   20170111    0.2
B   20170101    0.3
B   20170106    0.2
B   20170111    0.1
C   20170101    0.11
C   20170106    0.12
C   20170111    0.13
D   20170101    0.3
D   20170106    0.3
D   20170111    0.4
```

Description:I have one column with "id" and a lot of columns with dates, each column contains values od ndvi. I need to transpose every date to one column named "Dates" and values of that dates in other column named "NDVI_mean", the filed id must has to be repeated as many times as columns of dates we have

I can´t use the tool "transpose fields" of arcpy, only free code.

Please, help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `melt` function:

```
In [1611]: df
Out[1617]: 
  ID  20170101  20170106  20170111
0  A      0.31      0.10      0.20
1  B      0.30      0.20      0.10
2  C      0.11      0.12      0.13
3  D      0.30      0.30      0.40

In [1613]: pd.melt(df, id_vars='ID', var_name='Date', value_name="NDVI_mean").sort_values('ID')
    Out[1614]: 
   ID      Date  NDVI_mean
0   A  20170101       0.31
4   A  20170106       0.10
8   A  20170111       0.20
1   B  20170101       0.30
5   B  20170106       0.20
9   B  20170111       0.10
2   C  20170101       0.11
6   C  20170106       0.12
10  C  20170111       0.13
3   D  20170101       0.30
7   D  20170106       0.30
11  D  20170111       0.40
```

Let me know if it works.